# I want to show my facebook friend's birthday on my web site

Tags: javascript, facebook

I want to show my facebook friend's birthday on my web site.  How can I do that? Help me! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Graph API Explorer, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Ffriends%3Ffields%3Dname%2Cbirthday

This link will work once you set the proper access token.

- Click Get Access Token
- Navigate to Friends data permission
- Click friends_birthday
- Read the URL next to submit to see how to format the call in your application